# Utilize NuGet package with roslyn runtime compilation

Tags: c#, roslyn, fody-costura

Is it possible to utilize a NuGet package with runtime compilation?

I have to compile an EXE at runtime, and want to embed referenced .dll into my final .EXE to end up with a single file.

There is a NuGet package that does this at build time: https://github.com/Fody/Costura

I briefly read through the documents but it appears my use case would be an undocumented one. I was hoping someone here had experience with something similar.

Comment: You just need to add a reference to the DLL in your Compilation / Project.

Comment: @SLaks I don't think you follow the requirement. Adding the reference to the DLL at runtime does not produce an .exe with the embedded DLL.

Comment: You can embed the DLL as a resource like any other file.

Comment: And reference it in the code and call it's contained methods? It's not that simple. At least not what I have read.